# How to implement a navigation bar in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Starting with angularjs as a newbie I have created a navigation bar. It has several sub menus. But I am not completely sure what is the best practice to deal with it using angularjs. I would like to keep track of the current selected menu item to make it 'active' and change the rendered template depending on the selection.

I am looking for some examples or some example code, that can be used in production environment.

Sorry for this very generic question, but I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Use the $location service to change the current route, and know which route is currently displayed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199418/how-do-i-implement-the-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-with-angular-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It adds named views and states to your app. You can define "areas" in your main template that, based on the "state" your app is in, display a certain template+controller.

Edit: yes, $location could be enough for a simple application but by the time your one-per-screen controller gets to be 100 lines of $scope.$watch definitions you start realizing you need something more.

Comment: Thanks, that was the example I was looking for. I will have a closer look at it!