# navigation bar in single page app using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to find the answer to my problem with no luck. I'm new to web development and I've been trying to create a simple app using `angularjs` and `bootstrap`. There's no much content on my pages, only a couple of `inputs` and `buttons` that do nothing.
I placed `ng-view` in the **index.html** page as I saw in many tutorials and that allows me to navigate to all my pages. I'm trying to add a navigation bar to all my pages once a user logs in, so I placed another `ng-view` on my home(page after user logs in), but it seems that **angular** allows only one view for each app. And also it doesn't allow nested app. If I'm wrong, please correct me (that's what I understood from my Google 'research').
So, my question is: how can I add a navigation bar(or any same html content) to all my pages after the user logs in without copying the same code in each html page?
Btw, I had this working with `jQuery`, but I don't know how to do it using **angularjs**
Thanks!

Comment: [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) are the most common.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391727/how-to-implement-a-navigation-bar-in-angularjs

Comment: Also, consider using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: @Rob I tried with ng-include and it did what I needed. A snippet of html in each page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular Directive](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html) that use a template to create a custom tag and you can use a controller only for this directive. Call this tag to all pages when logging.