# how to maintain navbar/menu state when using PJAX and AngularJS

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a conceptual question ... I'm using jquery-pjax, Bootstrap, Python and AngularJS

When I initially load the page for the first time ( page refresh )
 - I know how to assign "active" to the correct place in Bootstrap's navbar menu ( because I have a URL variable that I access with Python )

But when I use pjax, it changes the URL but I'm not sure what's the topology I need to take to change the menu ?

Should I change by placing Angular ng-show ? because there's no really connection between jquery-pjax and AngularJS's app, or at least I'm not sure how to connect between them... ( kind of new to Angular )

Or maybe I should do it with Angular routes ? not sure it's a good idea as I have a one-page app kind of thing ... and I know that routes is used for multiple pages ..

Basically, since jquery-pjax just make the call, take the content from back-end and place it in a container and change the URL, I don't really have a way to get in the middle of this process to "ask" which page am I on now ?!

what other options I have ? I wonder how others are implementing it ... ( design speaking )

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18562339/202775

Comment: Thank you very much ! I hope that this is how everyone do it :)