# angular - Switch navbar when view is changed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, angular-routing

I am using angular-route.min.js and I have two designs for my navbar.

The First one is the landing page navbar that will appear first on my index.html. [image]

The second navbar is when the user is routed to the /signin page.[image]

I am unsure on how to go about this. I see a lot of different ways that this could be done, but none really that explain how I could change the entire header view when another route is chosen. They just show how to change the links that are contained inside of it. Like [this Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199418/how-do-i-implement-the-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-with-angular-js)

how can I switch out the header when it is routed to the /signin page?

also, I am working with another person who is doing the backend with Django. That is why I changed the "{{ }}" to "[[ ]]".

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

  $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/LandingPage.html',
  })

  .when('/signin', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/SignIn.html'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html'
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="app">

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular-route.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the codes of your **html** files?

Comment: no they are too large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ng-include` directive could solve the situation you are facing.

In controller code.

```
.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(/* EDIT: remove params for jshint */) {
        var path = $location.path();
        //EDIT: cope with other path
        $scope.templateUrl = (path==='/signin' || path==='/contact') ? 'template/header4signin.html' : 'template/header4normal.html' ;
    });
})
```

In Html.

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
        <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

I hope this could help you. :)

Comment: This worked great! How can I add other pages? like if I also wanted the '/contact' page to have that alternate header? I thought you would just add a Logical "or" which is | |, but that did not work. `app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, newurl, prevurl) {
        $scope.templateUrl = $location.path()==='/signin' || '/contact' ? 'pages/SigninHeader.html' : 'pages/NormalHeader.html' ;
    });
});`

Comment: also, I keep getting JSHint issues saying that "event, newurl, and prevurl are defined but never used." Is this an issue that I need to fix? if so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks for you to accept my answer! I edited my answer which includes `EDIT:` comments.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of your two `navbars` are not significant. An alternative is just use `ng-class` and `ng-show` to give different styles.

For example, in the `navbar.html`:

```
<nav>
    <span ng-show="isNormalPage">Inn</span>
    <img ng-class="{align-center: isNormalPage}">Logo</img>
    <span ng-show="isNormalPage">Sing in</span>
</nav>
```

In your JS file, add a flag to mark `singin` page:

```
.when('/signin', {
  controller: [$scope, function ($scope) {
      $scope.isNormalPage = false;
    };
  }]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was not looking to change the css. I just wanted to change the html of the header to the alternate one.