# How to set Bootstrap navbar "active" class in Angular 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, nav, angular2-routing

How can I set Bootstrap navbar "active" class in Angular 2? I only found [Angular 1 way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199418/how-do-i-implement-the-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-with-angular-js).

When I go to **About** page, add `class="active"` to **About**, and remove `class="active"` on **Home**.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['About']">About</a></li></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Although it is not exactly what you are looking for, I believe that routerLink automatically sets the class to **router-link-active** when that link is active.

So if its possible in your project, I would use the class .router-link-active in your css.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If you use the new 3.0.0. component router ( https://github.com/angular/vladivostok ) you can use the **routerLinkActive** directive. No further javascript required.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"> <a [routerLink]="['one']">One</a></li>
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"> <a [routerLink]="['second']">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

I used  "@angular/router": "^3.0.0-alpha.7"

Comment: Any counterpart in Dart?

Comment: still getting confused between `="active"` (wrong) and `="['active']"` (right). Thanks

Comment: @superjos probably for allowing multiple classes/values to be added if the current route is indeed in an active state

Comment: @superjos In addition to n15m0-jk's answer, you can add routerLinkActive="active" for only one class.

Comment: This is the perfect angularish 2 way... Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

Bert Deterd's answer is correct, but there's one thing that can be added.

If one route is a substring of another route, you will see something like this happen: [2 active anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHAwd.png)

You can add this to make it match exact routes only:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
```

Full Example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
  </li>
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
    <a [routerLink]="['/calendar']">Calendar</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I ran into this with the home route being just the app domain (empty string). It always showed as active.

Comment: I ran into an issue, whereby clicking outside the link (for example in the center of the web) made the li unactive. This was because I had the angular directives in the anchor tag instead of the a tag. In my head this has no difference, but it works in your way, mybae this comment helps somebody else. Thanks!

Comment: The perfect answer

Comment: Your  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" parameter really helps thanks. For those that are interested in what it does it to stops the active class from activating on the ['/'] Home page when the user is on a different page because it matches the path exactly as it is.

Comment: amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

For the latest version of Angular2 RC4 the following simple code works:

```
      <li [class.active]="router.url==='/about'"><a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a></li>
```

Using *import {Router} from "@angular/router";*
and put the router in the constructor.

Comment: working fine for me (Y) . But i have a doubt that what  i will do here incase of drop down menu.. example" <li class="dropdown"><ul> <li><a></li></ul></li>.". what we have to do if this is the scenario ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `isRouteActive` with `generate` from the <s>[Router](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/Router-class.html)</s> class.

According to docs:

> **generate(linkParams: any[]) : Instruction**
>
> Generate an Instruction based on the provided Route Link DSL.

and

> **isRouteActive(instruction: Instruction) : boolean**
>
> Given an instruction, returns true if the instruction is currently
>   active, otherwise false.

```
<li [class.active]="router.isRouteActive(router.generate(['/Home']))">
   <a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: In angular2 rc1, this must be changed to something like this: `[class.active]="router.urlTree.contains(router.createUrlTree(['Home']))"`. Also, I'd like to point out that router must be injected into the component like this: `constructor(public router: Router)`

Comment: To check for the root path `/`, I did `router.urlTree._root.children.length == 0`. Seems icky, but works.

Comment: Just a note here: if in your component your constructor looks like: constructor (private router:Router), all the above will work but you wont be able to build for production since router has private access.

Answer (score 5):

This does the trick (using RC5)

```
<li [class.active]="homeLink.classList.contains('active')">
    <a #homeLink routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

On RC2 that did not work for me. I ended up using

```
   <li  (click)="setActive('home')" class="{{getActive('home')}}"> <a [routerLink]="['/FullScreen']">Home</a></li>
```

and in the code behind tracked it

```
    currentChoice: string = "home";

   setActive(choice: string): void{
       this.currentChoice = choice;
   }

   getActive(choice: string) : string{
       if(this.currentChoice == choice)
            return "active";
       else
            return "not";

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In "@angular/router": "^3.3.1", the difference in the previous version is the bracket in the routerLinkActive

```
[routerLinkActive]="['active']"
```

In final release, ng2 will complain so just remove the bracket

```
routerLinkActive="active"
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
true}">Bob</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of multiple links
try this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> 
<li class="nav-item " routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Home </a></li>
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/aboutus">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gallery">Gallery</a>
 </li>
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/contactus">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version **"@angular/router": "^3.3.1"**

I simply put the name of the route, that I declare in my app.route.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DeclarationsComponent } from './declarations/declarations.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'declarations', pathMatch: 'full', component: DeclarationsComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

And in the view, I just write the name of the route

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a routerLink="declarations">SAV</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, HostBinding, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNavDropdown]'
})
export class NavDropdownDirective {
  isOpen:boolean =false;
  counter:number = 0;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) { }

  @HostBinding('class.open') get opened() {
    return this.isOpen;
  }

  @HostListener('click') onmouseClick()
  {
    this.counter++
    console.log();
    if(this.counter % 2 == 1)//odd
    {
      let part = this.render.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement);
      this.render.addClass(part,'open');
      this.isOpen = true;
    }else{
      let part = this.render.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement);
      this.render.removeClass(part,'open');
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
  }
  // @HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseLeave()
  // {
  //   let part = this.render.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement);
  //   this.render.removeClass(part,'open');
  //   this.isOpen = false;
  // }

  toggleClose() {
    // let part = this.render.parentNode(this.el.nativeElement)
    //this.menuclick = false;

  }
  toggle() {
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.toggle('open');
  }
}

/**
* Allows the dropdown to be toggled via click.
*/
@Directive({
  selector: '[appNavDropdownToggle]'
})
export class NavDropdownToggleDirective {
  constructor(private dropdown: NavDropdownDirective) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  toggleOpen($event: any) {
    console.log($event)
    $event.preventDefault();
  //  this.dropdown.toggleClose()
   this.dropdown.toggle();
  }
}

export const NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES = [NavDropdownDirective, NavDropdownToggleDirective];
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation.