# Using isRouteActive for determining if the route is active

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to use isRouteActive for determining if the particular route is active or not, but getting error,
**angular2.dev.js:23730 TypeError: l_context.isRouteActive is not a function**

```
<li [class.active]="isRouteActive(router.generate(['/Users']))"><a [routerLink]="['Users']">Users </a></li>
```

I have gone through the documentation, & surprised why there are two different documents for Router class.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

I am using 2.0.0-beta.12 version of Angular2.

It seems isRouteActive is not available in 2.0.0-beta.12. But I am unable  to figure out how to achieve the same.

Comment: How are you usiing it?

Comment: I am using it for highlighting the link with active class  for current route
 <li [class.active]="isRouteActive(router.generate(['/Users']))"><a [routerLink]="['Users']">Users </a></li>


I have also imported the Router class and defined router as a property.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is hard to read. Do you inject the `Router` how does your `isRouteActive()` method look like?

Comment: Thank you for your response  Günter Zöchbauer. It reminded me about the typo in my code. I have answered my question for the future reference. Thank You again.

Answer (score 3):

Ohkey, got it.

It was a typo in calling **isRouteActive**. I should have called it using **router.isRouteActive**.

So for using it,correctly

**in template:**

```
<li [class.active] = "router.isRouteActive(router.generate(['/Users']))">
```

Users

**in component:**

```
constructor(public router: Router){

}
```

Comment: As a best practice, we can make router a private variable and expose it using a method in class.

Answer (score 3):

Using angular 4+ router.isRouteActive was not working for me, instead used router.isActive which is listed in the docs as an official method did the trick. Main advantage to using this vs routerLinkActive property binding is that its helpful when you dont want to present a link in ui, only show some sort step indicator.

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#isActive

```
<li [class.active]="router.isActive('/my/routing/path')" ></li>
```

Comment: there is also second parameter `exact: boolean`

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick (using RC5)

```
<li [class.active]="homeLink.classList.contains('active')">
    <a #homeLink routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
</li>
```

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146324/1448419