# How to set Bootstrap navbar “active” class in Angular 4 using anchor jump?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-router

I looked at this question: [How to set Bootstrap navbar “active” class in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422526/how-to-set-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-in-angular-2) which shows how to link to a separate page. However, in my case I would like to link using an anchor to a section on the same page.

In the code mentioned below it's not escaping the string interpolation.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"> <a [routerLink]="['#'+sectionName]">One</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Its rendering as `href="/%23Home"` instead of `href="#Home"`

Answer (score 1):

use 'fragment="sectionName"' in your link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="education">
  link to user component
</a>
```

output: */#education*

More information: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the value to the `href` attribute instead of using a `routerLink` directive.

```
<a [href]="'#'+sectionName">One</a>
```

Or you could build your own directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[anchorLink]'
})
export class AnchorLinkDirective {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('attr.href')
  public get anchorLink() {
    return '#' + this.link;
  }

  public set anchorLink(value: string) {
    this.link = value;
  }

  @Input()
  public anchorLinkActive: string;

  private link: string;
  private ngUnsubscribe$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private router: Router, private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) {
    this.router.events.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$).subscribe(e => {
      if(e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let parts = e.urlAfterRedirects.split('#');
        let element = this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        if(this.anchorLinkActive && parts[parts.length - 1] === this.link) {
          this.renderer.addClass(element, this.anchorLinkActive);
        } else if(element.classList.contains(this.anchorLinkActive)) {
          this.renderer.removeClass(element, this.anchorLinkActive);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

**Note**: This directive is pretty basic and doesn't cover a change of the `anchorLinkActive` input.

Comment: Actually I also want to set the class as active when user clicks and navigates to the particular section that's why I tried using `routerLink`.