# Bootstrap 3.3.7 pills not remaining active

Tags: angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

the image shows the login and signup pills the login functionality is being displayed but its not highlighted.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syOWt.png)
the bootstrap pills that I added are not staying active once a pill is clicked the content is getting displayed and data toggle is also functioning but for both the contents only Login pill is remaining active.

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="LoginController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a  data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-login">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-signup">Sign-up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pills-login">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-signup">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**included cdns and scripts:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not staying active? Please replicate the problem in the fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and repose your question.

Comment: I edited the question so it makes a bit more sense now (the formatting was not showing the majority of the question due to parsing). Could still use more information (angular version, router, etc).

Comment: Thanks Brian. Angular version: 1.6

Comment: From what you have, the `class="active"` needs to be on the `<li>` element, not the link. But that said, I am wondering if you are trying to do this dynamically? So `<li role="presentation" class="active">`.

Comment: yes I am sorry about that yes the class should be on <li> so initially the Login pill is active and onclick of Signup the content of signup is getting displayed but the Login pill is active instead of Signup. How do I change that?

Comment: Are you using a router? Normally your header bits would be defined at a higher level of the app than within an individual controller. I would start looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199418/how-to-set-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-with-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, so bear with me... Is the highlight portion when selecting the login or signup is not working? Because I copied your code and it works perfectly...

```
<div class="tab-content">

                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pills-login">
                  Username:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  Password:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-signup">
                  Username:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  Password:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
          Email:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
          Contact:
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEzgXM?editors=1000

Also use codepen or some such and explain your predicament...